# Exception Handling - Catch with multiple exceptions not working as expected

Tags: java, exception

I have a catch block with multiple exceptions - Arithmetic and NullPointer and one catch block with Exception. I am calling a method from catch block, but it is not find the instance of exception correctly.

```
try {
        int a = 10/0;
    } catch (ArithmeticException | NullPointerException e) {
        Exce(e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Exce(e);
    }

public static void Exce(ArithmeticException ex) {
    System.out.println("Arithmetic");
}

public static void Exce(Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("Exception");
}
```

But i am getting output as "Exception"..I am not sure why Arithmetic is not getting displayed

When i have separate catch block for Arithmetic and Null pointer..I am able to print "Arithmetic"..But catch with multiple exceptions not working...

Comment: Why did you give both methods for printing the exception the same name, `Exce`? Try different names for each, like `HandleArithmetheticException` and `HandleGeneralException`.

Comment: @kshetline i think even if we change method names..result will be same. It will still execute HandleGeneralException and not HandleArithmeticException...

Comment: @Conffusion answer justifies it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you split the ArithmeticException and NullPointerException into 2 catch blocks, it works as you expect. I assume this is because variable e is declared of type Exception to be able to hold ArithmeticException and NullPointerException.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        int a = 10 / 0;
    } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        Exce(e);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Exce(e);            
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Exce(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
} catch (ArithmeticException | NullPointerException e) {
    Exce(e);
}
```

The *compile time* type of `e` in the above is the union of `ArithmeticException` and `NullPointerException`.  So when the compiler tries to match the type of `e` against the `Exce` methods:

- The `Exce(ArithmeticException)` overload is not applicable because at runtime `e` could be a `NullPointerException`.
- The `Exce(Exception)` overload is applicable because any value of `e` that matches the union of `ArithmeticException` and `NullPointerException` is an `Exception` as well.

Unfortunately, you cannot declare a method overload for the `ArithmeticException | NullPointerException` ... even if you wanted to:

- If you want to handle `ArithmeticException | NullPointerException` together like this, you could declare an overload like this:

  ```
  public static void Exce(RuntimeException ex) {
      System.out.println("RuntimeException");
  }
  ```
- Alternatively, catch `ArithmeticException` and `NullPointerException` separately.
- It is also possible to catch those two exception in one catch clause, and then discriminate them using (say) `instanceof` and type casts.  But it is a lot more code to do that.  (And a bad idea for other reasons.)